# GridView - Fragments - LongClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I hope that someone can help me :)

I have FragmentCategory, where where I change, which places will be shown in GridView.

I have always **OnClick**, but when I have fragment "pending", I want to have also **LongClick -> Then I will show MaterialDialog**

My OnClick:

```
        adapter = new AdapterPlaceGrid(getActivity(), items);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterPlaceGrid.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, Place p) {
            ActivityPlaceDetail.navigate((ActivityMain) getActivity(), v.findViewById(R.id.image), p);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can someone tell me, how can I make ***LongClick***?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: You can use callback method in your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use

```
adapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterPlaceGrid.OnItemLongCLickListener(){
@Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View v, Place p) {
        ....
    }
});
```

See this link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I cant. Look on my edited question :) Only onClick @joao86

Comment: is the AdapterPlaceGrid class a custom class?

Comment: Yes, It is, now I am trying to add it there :)

Comment: Well if it is you should be able to override onItemLongClickListener from the super class from which you are extending from. ;)

Comment: Nice, it works :) :) It was in adapter and then I was (no idea why) implementing Android OnItemLongClick instead the one from adapter.

Comment: Cool ;) happy to help